# how to dynamic create a mongoid class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I want to dynamic create a mongoid model and do some search.

At first, I create a file named **daily_pageview.rb**

```
class DailyPageview
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :path, type: String
end
```

Then, I run these commands in `$ rails c`

```
DailyPageview.create!(path: '/')
DailyPageview.where(:path => '/').count
```

Correctly, I got a result: 1.

Then I try to refactor my code, I delete **daily_pageview.rb**

Also, I run these commends in **rails c**

```
c = Class.new do
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Timestamps
   field :path, type: String
end
Object.const_set 'DailyPageview', c 


DailyPageview.where(:path => '/').count
```

But, this time, I got 0. Why?

I'm not sure that is it related to this issue [mongoid failing with dynamic collections](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3866) or this is my problem.

Comment: This may be an omission - but in example 2 you are not actually persisting any `DailyPageview`s. You would need to do `DailyPageview.create!(path: '/')` to get the same result as in example 1.

Comment: Hi, @papirtiger， Because, in first commend: DailyPageview.create!(path: '/') , I already create a record in collection. So, I don't write again.